# How to show that if there is a injective function $f : A \rightarrow B$, then there is a injective and monotone $g : A \rightarrow B$ too

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have $A,B \subseteq  \mathbb{N}$ non-empty subsets of natural numbers. How to show that if there is a injective function $f : A \rightarrow B$, then there is a injective AND monotone $g : A \rightarrow B$ too.

And is it true that  if there are injective functions $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow A$ then there is also a bijective function $h: A \rightarrow B$

Comment: At least as a first approach I would divide into cases according to whether $A$ is finite or infinite. (Later on it may be that you can combine both cases in one wording).

Comment: For the second question: **Yes**; this is the celebrated [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

The construction of the monotone injective function $g:A\rightarrow B$ is as follows: Let $A=\{a_1, a_2, ...\}.$ an ordered arrangement of $A$. Define  $g(a_1)=\min f(A), g(a_2)=\min (f(A)- \{g(a_1\}),g(a_3)=\min (f(A)-\{g(a_1), g(a_2)\}) ...$
This might help in answering your second question also.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the second question is yes, it's the Schröder-Bernstein theorem. It's valid in general and do **not** require $A$ and $B$ to be subset of $\mathbb N$.